# Uploading files to google drive using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, google-drive-api

I already created folders and fetched them in my application using swift 3 
Now I'm trying to upload audio files to a selected folder , I started trying with an image , and here is the code i've wrote :

```
let folderId: String = folders[indexPath.row].folderId
    let metadata = GTLRDrive_File.init()
    metadata.name = "weather"
    metadata.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.photo"
    metadata.parents = [folderId]

    guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "weather", ofType: "png") else {
        return
    }
    guard let fileData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: filePath) else {

        return
    }

    print("result: \(fileData.count) bytes")


    let imageFromPath = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)!
    selectedimg.image = imageFromPath

    let uploadParameters = GTLRUploadParameters(data: fileData , mimeType: "image/png")
    uploadParameters.shouldUploadWithSingleRequest = true
    let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate.query(withObject: metadata, uploadParameters: uploadParameters)
    query.fields = "id"
    self.service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: {(ticket:GTLRServiceTicket, object:Any?, error:Error?) in
        if error == nil {
            //  print("File ID \(files.identifier)")
        }
        else {
            print("An error occurred: \(error)")
        }
    })
```

But when i check my drive , the image is just an empty Google doc , 0 bytes .
I tried to show to image from the filePath and printed the fileData size and all is alright .
I would like some help with this problem and how to fix it . Thanx in advance

**Update**
I managed to work it out , i've just removed this line

```
metadata.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.photo"
```

Comment: you got any response?

Comment: I got a success every time

Comment: All you have done is upload the file meta data you need to actually upload the file itself.  https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you for your response , can you please provide me  the code in swift 3 because i have no idea how to convert this objective c

Comment: Nope sorry I am a google api expert not a swift expert.   I am sure if you do a bit of Googleing you will find some examples.

Comment: @DaImTo Please see the update in the post , thanx to you it worked